# Auto login with JQuery Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, timer, countdown

the question is how I can create an auto login page with JQuery ajax? I also need it to work in a countdown manner. I mean I'm creating a login page, which will help shorten my testing time and I will also use these skills for to generate some other http requests in other things...

So it currently looks like this but it doesn't work:

```
<h1> 
    Auto Authentication in 2 seconds.
</h1>

<p>
    <script src="/GenTreeUploader/javascript/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(
            $.ajax("j_security_check", {
            j_username: "admin",
            j_password: "blogas"
        }););
    </script>
</p>
```

And it also doesn't have time countdown, because I don't know how to do that. Can somebody help me please? I'm not very familiar with JQuery and barely remember anything at all right now.

Comment: What exactly does an auto login page do, and why would it need a timer? Why not just skip authentication for testing?

Comment: @MattGibson Well I'm testing some web page functions, which require the web interface. So to turn off authentication I'd also have to change web.xml. Well I also need this info to know how to make other kinds of timed requests which I will need later, so it also has a purpose of an example. :) If you have more tipps or better ideas i'd be glad if you'd suggest.

Answer (score 2):

You need the Javascript setTimeout method:

```
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax("j_security_check", { j_username: "admin", j_password: "blogas" } );
  }, 2000);
});
```

Where 2000 is in milliseconds. See W3Schools for more info:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "j_security_check",
     data: { j_username: "John", j_password: "Boston" }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
     alert( msg );
    });
  }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried, but it didn't seem to do anything, is there something wrong with my $(document).ready(? how do I execute this script? I thought $(document).ready( would do it?

Comment: Now it did work, when I removed the ";", why didn't I need the ";"? I thought it's used after every "...()" ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function() {   
     setTimeOut(function() {
          $.post("verify.php", { j_username: "admin", j_password: "blogas" }
          });
    } ,2000);
});
```

And in the PHP page you could include some checks from a databse or whatever whether the username and password are correct.